# the function doesn't work correctly

Tags: vim

Today, I upgraded my Vim from 7.3 to 7.4. However, the below function, `CleverTab()`, doesn’t seem to work. (I am not sure if the matter is the update.)

```
function! CleverTab()
    if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"
    endif
    if pumvisible()
        return "\<C-N>"
    endif
    return "hello"
endfunction

inoremap <silent><tab> <C-R>=CleverTab()<CR>
```

The purpose of this function is to do something different depending on the current condition when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed:

1. If the current line is filled with space, then just add a tab.
2. If a popup menu appears, move down.
3. Otherwise, add the string “hello”.

(To be honest, what I want to do in scenario 3 is to call another function. But whatever — to make the problem easy, I’m just trying to show a string in that case.)

Suppose I’m editing my file via Vim and have typed the string “123” (for instance). At the moment, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the actual result is that a `<tab>` is added. The expected result is that the flow should go to condition 3 and add the string “hello”. I have spent this afternoon on it.

So, can anyone help me to figure it out? Appreciated!

Comment: tested your function and mapping, "hello" was printed on my vim 7.4. BTW, you can create a `<expr>` map instead of `<C-r>=`, that is designed for this situation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it still does work for me. so could you please help to let me know if there is anything blocked my function CloverTab()?

Comment: sorry for typo mistake. it still does NOT work!

Comment: check if your `<tab>` was mapped by some other mapping. `:verbose imap <tab>`

Comment: yes, there is an function in other vim script blocked mine. So now, is there any wany to let my function override that one? my CleverTab() is in the .vimrc file, while that one is in .vim/autoload folder. I need both of them for sure, which means i cannot delete any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CleverTab()` function is global in scope. If another plugin defines the same function, the former will be overridden. To avoid such conflicts, global functions are to be avoided. Rather, use script-local functions `s:CleverTab()`, to be invoked from a mapping via `<SID>CleverTab()`, or autoload functions `myplugin#CleverTab()`.

If the issue is that another plugin overrides your `<Tab>` mapping, you have to choose another mapping key, or decide for one or the other. Only when your function is an extension of the original (and provides compatible return types), you can invoke the other function from inside yours (provided you've used different function names, as described in my first paragraph).